# Emulate PHP date calculation using Joda Time

Tags: java, php, jodatime

I'm using the [Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) to subtract one month from a LocalDate:

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2013, 3, 31);
System.out.println(date.minusMonths(1));
```

The result is 2013-02-28, which is what I would intuitively expect and which is also documented in the [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#minusMonths%28int%29):

> If subtracting months makes the day-of-month invalid, it is adjusted to the last valid 
>   day in the month.

However, in my current project I need to be compatible with some existing PHP code like this:

```
$date = new \DateTime('2013-03-31');
echo $date->sub(new \DateInterval('P1M'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

The result here would be 2013-03-03, i.e. it is "rolling over" to the next month.

How can I achieve the same behaviour using Joda Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP seems to subtract the number of days it finds in the previous month. This should do it with Joda:

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2013, 3, 31);
int numberOfDays = date.minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
System.out.println(date.minusDays(numberOfDays));
```